# Should I stick to the fork oil weight specified?

Tags: suspension

I've got a pair of Rockshox Reba race forks. I'm going to service them. Fork oil weight says 5wt but in the past I have generally used a heavier oil weight 7.5 / 10 wt due to my size. However, saying that, the rebound damping is so effective and adjustable on this fork that I don't have any problems like I used to- should I stick to the 5wt?

Comment: In general, you should stick to manufacturer's recommendations unless you have a strong reason otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rockshox recommends using 5wt in the upper and 15wt in the lower legs of the Reba, and differing the PSI to tailor for rider weight.

140-160lbs = 90 - 105psi

160-180lbs = 105 - 120psi

180-200lbs = 120 - 135psi

200-220llbs = 135+

MAX PSI = 200

Although changing to heavier weights for heavier riders is not uncommon, i would stick with the recommended weight, especially if its working fine for you with tuning the rebound.

Sourced from the [Sram 2014 Suspension fork air/oil charts](https://www.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/gen0000000004392_rev_a_rockshox_oil_air_and_coil_chart_2014_0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If it works as it is then leave it alone and use the 5wt. Your unlikely to harm the fork but might end up in a situation where the damping no longer performs at the level you are used to.

Using a heavier or lighter weight is normally only done to alter the damping performance where the fork either does not offer adjustment, or the rider wishes to tune the fork beyond the adjustments offered.